# Can the Python condition variable give its notifyl to the C++ program to run by pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, pybind11

there is a condition variable in my Python class Selector.

```
class Selector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)
        self._cv = Condition()
    def _changed(self):
        with self._cv:
            self._cv.notify_all()
    def _set_observer(self, channel_actions, observer):
        for channel, _ in channel_actions:
            channel.set_observer(observer)
    def select(
            self,
            *args: ty.Tuple[RecvPort, ty.Callable[[], ty.Any]],
    ):
        with self._cv:
            self._set_observer(args, self._changed)
            while True:
                start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                for channel, action in args:
                    if channel.probe():
                        self._set_observer(args, None)
                        return action()
                self._cv.wait()
```

I want to I want to pass the function `_changed()` into a cpp class(the RecvPort), and let the cpp class run the python funtion `_changed()` to `notify_all`.
So, I use the function `Set_observer(std::function observer)` in class RecvPort. and expose class RecvPort's function Set_observer as ser_observer by pybind11.
and the I will open a thread to run the following class RecvPort's function.

```
void ShmemRecvPort::QueueRecv() {
  while (!done_.load()) {
    bool ret = false;
    if (this->recv_queue_->AvailableCount() > 0) {
      bool not_empty = recv_queue_->Probe();
      ret = shm_->Load([this, &not_empty](void* data){
        MetaDataPtr metadata_res = std::make_shared<MetaData>();
        MetaDataPtrFromPointer(metadata_res, data,
                               nbytes_ - sizeof(MetaData));
        this->recv_queue_->Push(metadata_res);
        if (observer && !not_empty) {
          observer();
          }
      });
```

but I always get the segmentation fault:

> ```
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV(11), Segmentation fault.
> ```

I check my err info. it sames the observer is a nullptr when excute the `observer()` although it passes the if.

I want to excute the python function in cpp